# Parsing color no longer working with hex values

Tags: java, android

This is strange, I have used this function before. however it seems to have stopped working and I am not sure why.

I use `Color.parseColor` to set a background color of an item.
This is the code doing it:

```
imgItemImage.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(cartItem.get("picture")));
```

I am getting this exception:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "#837A67"
>
> at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:579)
>
> at android.graphics.Color.parseColor(Color.java:1386)

That appears to be a correct hex color so I am unsure why it would be causing this exception.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: There might be hidden characters in the string value. Try printing the length, i.e. `cartItem.get("picture").length()`. If I'm right, it's not 7.

Comment: @Andreas Wow, I did not even think about that! you are correct, I got a length of 8! You are brilliant! Thank you!

Comment: @Derek And what was the offending character? A simple space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from the `Exception`, the problem is when `Long.parseLong()` is being called from inside `Color.parseColor()`.

This `Exception` is due to wrong input being given to **Long.parseLong()** which is an extra character of `#`, which should normally be removed by `Color.parseColor()` before internally calling `Long.parseLong()`.

The `Exception` thrown by your code can demonstrated below:

```
String str = "#837A67";
System.out.println(Long.parseLong(str, 16));
```

Where `16` is the RADIX for hexadecimal.

But try this:

```
String str = "837A67";
System.out.println(Long.parseLong(str, 16));
```

And you will get the expected results.

This shows that the `String` getting passed through `parseColor` is not correct because the `#` is not getting removed during `Color.parseColor()` most likely due to a *different* character getting removed instead.

Double check into the value you are passing to `Color.parseColor()` and ensure there are not any characters before the `#`.